# Two vertical Linear Layouts and want one wider than the other

Tags: android-studio

I have a layout that is a relativeLayout that contains 2 vertical Linear layouts. Each of the linear layouts is using equal width. The orientation is landscape and I would like to make the first Linear layout to use 2/3 of the layout and the second linearlayout use the other 1/3.
I am not well versed in XML. My background has been in Visual Basic and now moving to Java using Android Studio.

Here is the XML for the layout of activity.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="@color/colorBackgroundGray"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_select_item"
        tools:context="com.myCompany.myProduct.activities.ReturnAreaActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        >
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/FragmentFrame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


        </FrameLayout>
        <include
            android:id="@+id/include2"
            layout="@layout/frm1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1.7" />



    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/include"
            layout="@layout/layout_numpad5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="220dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.3"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            />

    </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

The weight is something I just tried. Any ideas?
[image]

Comment: You want two inner linear layout side by side OR one below another?

Answer (score 0):

**Try Below basic logic it will work fine in your case**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="3">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="First Linear Layout"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Second Linear Layout"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

> Output :

[image]

> To change orientation (If you wan't layouts side by side) just change value or android:orientation="vertical" to android:orientation="horizontal".
>
> OUTPUT :

[image]